# How to binding tooltip of a textbox to a label in style of it

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I try to create a HINT for textbox, and this is my style code for all TextBox in my application:

[image]

I already set Tooltip for this textbox (1)

I want that binding the value of ToolTip the TextBox (3)

Right now, i only can make the "Search..." appear (2)

please help

update code

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BTL.Themes">


<Style xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
       x:Key="TextField"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BodyForeground1}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BodyForeground1}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="250" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextFieldNormalBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <VisualBrush x:Key="Hint"
                                 AlignmentX="Left"
                                 AlignmentY="Center"
                                 Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Label Content="Search..." Foreground="LightGray" />
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                  Margin="0 0 0 0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledOpacity}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 2" />-->
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BodyFocusVisual}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Hint}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Show your source code, but not as Image...

Comment: just update code, please take a look
I want something like this:
 <Label Content="Binding ToolTip" Foreground="LightGray" />
(ofcourse, It not work)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TemplateBinding` to bind the label content to the tooltip of the textbox and whatever value you assign to the `textboxName.ToolTip` will be displayed as the label content.

```
<VisualBrush.Visual>
    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" Foreground="LightGray" />
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```